# Tensor product of a unit vector with itself

Tags: tensor-products

Can anything be said about the tensor $p(a \otimes a)$ where $\otimes$ is the tensor product and $a$ is a unit vector, and $p$ is a constant? Is there a special way of writing it down maybe or a way to know what the individual components of the matrix are?

Comment: Have you identified the tensor $p(a\otimes a)$ with the matrix $(p\cdot a_i\cdot a_j)_{i,j}$?

Comment: Well, many things can be said about many things. What do you actually want to know?